# Where in the world is Version Cue in CS5?

Tags: version-control, version

Just upgraded to Adobe version Cue CS5 from CS4 and now I can't see any options for turning on Version Cue server. Is this an optional install? Don't see anything in CS5 installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude Adobe CS5 discontinued Version Cue last year. See [this post (http://versioncue.info/?p=40)](http://versioncue.info/?p=40)  for the history of version Cue. You won't be able to upgrade, you need to find alternatives to version Cue.

Comment: Thanks TBD for the Version Cue release timeline. Didn't realize after nearly 7 years, Adobe dropped it in CS5. Time to look for an alternative. Any suggestions?

Comment: Depends what your requirements are, my team (flex/flash devs & creative designers) found a solution [Evolphin Zoom](http://evolphin.com) that worked for us. Its well supported by a company that is focused on versioning, so hopefully it won't go extinct like Adobe CS5 version cue did :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, we should have looked before we leaped.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this thread post : [Where is Version Cue CS5?](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2788406)

> While the Version Cue Server is no longer being offered in CS5, Adobe Drive is, and it has the ability to integrate with 3rd party DAMS, thus the checkin-checkout options in some Adobe CS5 applications will work with Adobe Drive connected to a 3rd party system. For more information, please see:
>   http://www.adobe.com/products/versioncue/

Adobe's plan for Version Cue : [Details on Adobe's CS5 Plans for Version Cue](http://www.creativepro.com/article/details-adobes-version-cue-plans)

Comment: Thanks but I am so mad at Adobe, I am not trusting them again with versioning stuff again.